# Как при делении с остатком -1 на 24 получается 23?

Tags: python

Не могу уловить математическую логику этого деления с остатком. Вернее, не припоминаю каких-либо свойств деления числа с остатком, которые объяснили бы этот результат.

Comment: Это прямо следует из определения остатка от деления, и из того факта - что остаток от деления - неотрицательное число.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC раздел «знак остатка». Кратко: оба варианта имеют смысл в разных случаюях

Answer (score 0):

23 это остаток от деления. 
На 24 без остатка делятся 0 и - 24.

Остаток от деления получается вычитанием из делимого максимального числа которое делится на делитель и меньше делимого.

-1-(-24)=23