# Как работает % и // при делении отрицательных чисел в Python?

Tags: python

Как работает % и // при делении отрицательных чисел в Python?

Например почему?:

-9 // 5 = -2

-9 % 5 = 1

Comment: См. также [Как при делении с остатком -1 на 24 получается 23?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1083289/1365)

Comment: @insolor, Добавил в плашку тоже

Comment: -2 * 5 + 1 = -9